# How can I get node name while I am using orderByChild in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Here's my Code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Query queryRef  = mdatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("age");
    queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                User users = chatSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                String name = users.getName();
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

As you guys probably guessed, this code is for displaying a users name. But what I actually want to do is, based on the same query result, I want to display their User ids,not name. I tried using a class like this to get the user id:

```
public class User{
private String gender;
private Long age;
private String email;
private Long height;
private Long weight;
private String name;
private String type;
private String userId;

public User()
{

}
public User(String gender,Long age,String email,Long height,Long weight,String name,String type,String userId)
{
    this.gender=gender;
    this.age=age;
    this.email=email;
    this.height=height;
    this.weight=weight;
    this.name=name;
    this.type=type;
    this.userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
}

public String getId()
{
    return userId;
}

public String getGender()
{
    return gender;
}

public Long getAge()
{
    return age;
}

public String getEmail()
{
    return email;
}

public Long getHeight()
{
    return height;
}

public Long getWeight()
{
    return weight;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getType()
{
    return type;
}}
```

But this returned the current users id 3 times, since I've 3 users in my DB, not individual user ids.
Here's my DB:

Each user have this many values

[image: Each user have this many values]

Another method I tried was using getKey() like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Query queryRef  = mdatabase.child("Users").orderByChild("age");
queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = snapshot.getKey();
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
```

But this returned the node 'Users' 3 times, not the User ids.

Can anyone help me with this? I want to display their User ids.That is, these:

OMbACIWg3fOurXy8SEqQD8TAQl12, kZllc0GL1Vfbitt73WHWwJuXvXC2, lxVykDo9GQRcFmb0u1QZ0WCc9lg2
(based on the picture)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `getKey()` method at the wrong `DataSnapshot`.
This is what you want

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        String key = chatSnapshot.getKey();
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

EDIT: To set the userId to the `User` class

```
for (DataSnapshot chatSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
    User user = chatSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    user.setUserId(chatSnapshot.getKey());
}
```

Comment: Thank You! It works perfectly now! :D
Just out of curiosity, is there a way to get the UserId using the class I mentioned in the question?

Comment: it's not possible, you have to set it manually. I have updated my answer for this. @JacobCelestine